# MP3 Player add song bugged

Tags: c#, wpf

I've been developing a MP3 player in WPF CSharp and when I add a mp3 file, it adds normally, but when I add another mp3 file separately the name of the newly added mp3 file is the same as the first added one here's my code:

```cs
private List<String> Files = new List<string> { };
private List<String> Paths = new List<string> { };

private void AddSong_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        mediaPlayer.Stop();
        for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            Files.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileNames[i]));
            Paths.Add(ofd.FileNames[i]);
            Playlist.Items.Add(Files[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You might be studying a computer science degree, but that doesn't mean this particular question should be tagged with [computer-science]

Comment: I can't see the point in having two arrays that store the same thing; you can always work out Files from Paths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're adding in `Files[i]`, but `i` is not the right index to be using there. Instead, add in the most recent file, `System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileNames[i])`.

(This is a problem when the `Files` is not empty when you add extra files, as you observed.)

```
private List<String> Files = new List<string> { };
private List<String> Paths = new List<string> { };

private void AddSong_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.Multiselect = true;
    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        int InitialFilesLength = Files.Length;
        mediaPlayer.Stop();
        for (int i = 0; i < ofd.FileNames.Length; i++)
        {
            Files.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileNames[i]));
            Paths.Add(ofd.FileNames[i]);
            Playlist.Items.Add(Files[i - InitialFilesLength]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah I figured it out a minute ago... But thanks for helping

Comment: Or even, put a `using` for System.IO, store `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(ofd.FileNames[i])` into a variable and use the variable twice

Comment: Or using `Files[i - initialFileLength]` where `initialFilesLength = Files.length` is defined before the `for` loop.